# system call that prints output as in the terminal

Tags: python-3.x

A terminal command that we type in the terminal might print some output on the terminal. When we use this command in a python script and call a system call say:

```
os.system('ls')
```

we do obtain the output, but somehow it returns an integer to indicate a successful execution of the process:

```
>>> x = os.system('ls')    #prints some output
>>> x
>>> 0
```

I need a function that stores the output in x as a string that I need to parse. What is the python function that does this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the subprocess module.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
proc = Popen(["ls"], stdout=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

Or if you're using Python 3.5 or greater, then run is recommended.

```
import subprocess

completed = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8")

#output is stored in completed.stdout
```